# Can't pass a variable outside nest Try cath?

Tags: java, try-catch

I am using a CSV file to create a deck of cards and i am supposed to handle the user entering wrong paths or corrupted CSV files in term but i can't get the variable filepath outside the nested try catch block

```
 public ArrayList<Card> loadCardsFromFile(String path) throws IOException {

            ArrayList<Card> resultDeck = new ArrayList<Card>();
            String currentLine = "";
            String [] result = currentLine.split(",");
            Scanner sc =  new Scanner(System.in);
            FileReader fileReader = null;
            String filepath = "";
            String temp = "";
            try {
                    fileReader = new FileReader(path);
                    Deck.throwingMethod(fileReader);
            } catch(FileNotFoundException | UnknownSpellCardException 
                    | UnknownCardTypeException | EmptyFieldException | MissingFieldException e) {
                boolean flag;
                for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                      System.out.println("Please enter a correct path:");
                      try {
                           if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                              filepath = sc.nextLine();
                              fileReader = new FileReader(filepath);
                           }    

                              Deck.throwingMethod(fileReader);
                              flag = true;
                      } catch(FileNotFoundException | UnknownSpellCardException 
                              | UnknownCardTypeException | EmptyFieldException | MissingFieldException e1) {
                           if(i >= 3) {
                              sc.close();
                              e1.printStackTrace();
                              throw e1;
                           }
                           System.out.println("The file was not found or is malformed");
                           flag = false;
                      }
                      if(flag) {
                         break;
                      }
                }
            }
            sc.close();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            MonsterCard card;
            SpellCard spell = new CardDestruction("Just for the sake","of instantiating");
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    result = currentLine.split(",");
                    if(result[0].equals("Monster")) {
                        card = new MonsterCard(result[1], result[2], Integer.parseInt(result[5])
                                      ,Integer.parseInt(result[3]), Integer.parseInt(result[5]));
                        resultDeck.add(card);
                    } else if(result[0].equals("Spell")) {
                         switch(result[1]) {
                           case "Card Destruction": spell = new CardDestruction(result[1], result[2]);  
                                break;
                           case "Change Of Heart": spell = new ChangeOfHeart(result[1], result[2]); 
                                break;
                           case "Dark Hole": spell = new DarkHole(result[1], result[2]); 
                                break;
                           case "Graceful Dice": spell = new GracefulDice(result[1], result[2]); 
                                break;
                           case "Harpie's Feather Duster": spell = new HarpieFeatherDuster(result[1], result[2]); 
                                break;
                           case "Heavy Storm": spell = new HeavyStorm(result[1], result[2]); 
                                break;
                           case "Mage Power": spell = new MagePower(result[1], result[2]); 
                                break;
                           case "Monster Reborn": spell = new MonsterReborn(result[1], result[2]); 
                                break;
                           case "Pot of Greed": spell = new PotOfGreed(result[1], result[2]); 
                                break;
                           case "Raigeki": spell = new Raigeki(result[1], result[2]); 
                                break;
                         }
                           resultDeck.add(spell);
                    }
            }  
                    br.close();
                    return resultDeck;                    
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly do you need to access the filepath and for what purpose?

Comment: Not too sure what you are trying to do here - it looks like you get three attempts to enter the path, if you do enter it successfully, then "filepath" will be set to the last answer given and this IS accessible outside the try...catch. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct, it should but at the part where i initialize BufferedReader, it seems that the constructor gets null passed, i tested it a thousand times but i can't seem to get fileReader or filepath out of the try catch block

Comment: no need for testing BufferedReader just trying to print filepath out of the try catch block doesn't produce anything

Comment: @RealSkeptic to access the filepath it needs to exist ofcourse and the fields and the fields inside to conform with certain conditions i set inside throwingMethod

Answer (score 1):

When you enter the outer catch block, fileReader can be null if the FileReader constructor threw an exception when called with path.

When you enter the inner catch block on any loop iteration, fileReader can be null if the scanner never had a next line, or if the FileReader constructor threw an exception on every loop iteration up to and including the current one.

When you reach the buffered reader constructor, fileReader will be null unless you successfully made it through both the FileReader constructor and throwingMethod, either on the original attempt or on some loop iteration.

If you have access to a symbolic debugger, you can step through the code and see what is happening. If not, you can add lots of extra println statements to see exactly what path you are taking through the code and the values of all the relevant variables.